# problem with filter in json dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks

First of all, thanks you for you time. I work in pyspark with databricks, I try filter a columns from json dataframe but dont working... I try others alternatives, how in example df.where(col('name_column')) and but with out result.

I have the next code:

```
df_json = spark.read.json('/mnt/datalake/route/*.json').filter(array_contains("column_name", "value"))
```

Also I try this:

```
df_json = spark.read.json('/mnt/datalake/route/*.json').filter(array_contains($"column_name", "value"))
```

Why no function?, I want filter all result from dataframe, I try read the documentation but I dont result...

I attentive for you response, thanks!

Comment: "Why no function?"  Can you clarify the question?  What error are you getting? 
and could you add the output of `spark.read.json('/mnt/datalake/route/*.json').printSchema()`?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is:

df_json = df_json.filter("ColumnName == 'Value'")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).